# Unpacking tuples using "Either" in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get a grip on how tuples work in Haskell.

I came across this  type constructor `leftRight :: (Either a b -> c) -> (a -> c, b -> c)` and I'm struggling to see what it does.

So we have `(Either a b -> c)`which means that either a is applied to c or b is applied to c. But the output is a tuple?
Does that mean that it splits the function so that left side of the tuple takes in argument given at a and right side takes argument given at right?
How would this look in code?

Comment: The input is a function and the output is *two functions*. The tuple is barely relevant, except that it groups the two functions together into a single output. Does that help you figure it out?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, I see that, but I still don't understand how it ends up being a tuple.. How can one argument make two functions?

Comment: why couldn't it? unrelated example: if you have the number 42 as argument, you can make the functions `(*) 42` which multiplies by 42, and `(+) 42` which adds 42

Comment: Consider `f :: Either A B -> C; f (Left a) = {- produce a C from the available a::A -}; f (Right b) = {- produce a C from the available b::B -}` vs. `fLeft :: A -> C; f a = {- produce a C from the available a::A -}; fRight :: B -> C; f b = {- produce a C from the available b::B -}`. Do you agree that `f` and `fLeft+fRight` look very much like two different ways of representing the same information? Do you think you could write a function that could convert any `f` into its constituent `fLeft` and `fRight`? (That is the task `leftRight` performs.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So we have `Either a b -> c` which means that either `a` is applied to `c` or `b` is applied to `c`

Wrong, or at least badly worded. Nothing is “applied to `c`” here.

What it actually means is: the function can accept an `a`-value or a `b`-value, and in either case produces a `c`-value.

This is equivalent to having both a function that accepts only `a`-values and gives `c`-results, and one that accepts only `b`-values and gives `c`-results. The tuple groups both of these functions together.

It might help to look at an example to illustrate:

```
fryPancake :: Either Butter Margarine -> Pancake
```

<sup>[Assume we've already taken care of the flour, eggs etc. in the batter]</sup>

From this you can obtain both

```
fryPancakeWithButter :: Butter -> Pancake
fryPancakeWithButter b = fryPancake (Left b)

fryPancakeWithMargarine :: Margarine -> Pancake
fryPancakeWithMargarine m = fryPancake (Right m)
```

Now you just group both of these together:

```
fryPancake' :: (Butter -> Pancake, Margarine -> Pancake)
fryPancake' = (fryPancakeWithButter, fryPancakeWithMargarine)
```

...which is the same as

```
fryPancake' = leftRight fryPancake
```

Answer (score 5):

"I came across this type constructor..."

It's not a type constructor - it's a function type declaration.

The `->` separates out the parameter types. The final one is the return type, and the previous ones are the input types.

Hence `leftRight :: (Either a b -> c) -> (a -> c, b -> c)` takes one input and returns one output.

- Input function: `(Either a b -> c)`
- Output function pair: `(a -> c, b -> c)`

The parentheses contain the functions.

The first function takes an Either type (left value is the error type, `a`, and the right value is the OK type, 'b' - it helps me to think of the latin, sinister for left, and dexter for right - your mileage may vary) as the input and returns something of type `c`.

The second function comes as a tuple of two separate functions, one is `a -> c`, and one is `b -> c`.

A concrete version: type `a` is a String to contain my error message, type `b`is an Int, and type `c` is another string.

`leftRight :: (Either String Int -> String) -> (String -> String, Int -> String)`

Comment: Alternative mnemonic: right is Right (and wrong is Left). But the standard interpretation of `Either` as an error-ish type doesn't really seem like it applies here.

Answer (score 4):

The input to `leftRight` is a function and the output is *two functions*. The tuple is barely relevant, except that it groups the two functions together into a single output, so `leftRight` can return both of them at once.

One function's type is `a -> c` and the other one's type is `b -> c`. Presumably, the first function wraps the `a` in `Left` and then calls the original function, and the second one wraps the `b` in `Right` and then calls the original function:

```
leftRight :: (Either a b -> c) -> (a -> c, b -> c)
leftRight original = (leftFunc, rightFunc)
    where
        leftFunc aVal = original (Left aVal)
        rightFunc bVal = original (Right bVal)
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is to use function composition. A function of type `a -> c` can be created from functions of type `a -> Either a b` and `Either a b -> c`. You have `Left :: a -> Either a b` and you have the argument `f :: Either a b -> c` passed to `leftRight`.

The same argument lets you construct a function of type `b -> c` similarly. This gives you

```
leftRight :: (Either a b -> c) -> (a -> c, b -> c)
leftRight f = let g1 = ...
                  g2 = ...
              in (g1, g2)
```

I leave the definitions of `g1` and `g2` as an exercise.